# Select first unique child

Tags: c#, linq

I need to 'distinctly' select the first of each item by parent id, as per the following:

```
// 'children' is a collection of Child ordered by parent
var last = 0;
var result = new List<Child>();
foreach (var c in children)
{
    if (c.Parent.Id != last)
    {
        result.Add(c);
        last = c.Parent.Id;
    }
}
```

How can I do this as a Linq query?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Showing my failed attempts won't illustrate the question any better.

Comment: Predictable childish downvote

Comment: Hope you don't think that was me. I still can't down-vote! lol

Comment: Haha no, just something I'm used to :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and select the first item in each group:

```
List<Child> result = children.GroupBy(c => c.Parent.Id)
                             .Select(g => g.First())
                             .ToList();
```